# Make sure input Double has certain format

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift3, decimal

I would like to check if a certain Double input is of the form: "the number has maximum one decimal". So what would be ok is, for example,

```
100 //this is ok
100.3 //this is ok
100.3 //this is ok 
1.333 //this is not ok 
10.333 //this is not ok
```

I tried using a regex, but somehow it doesn't work. Is there any easier solution I could use?

I've used this code

```
func validate(input: Double) -> Bool {
    let regex = "^[1-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{1})?$"

    let inputTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
    return inputTest.evaluate(with: String(input))
}
```

Comment: So, what regex did not work as expected? How did you use it? Please show the failing the code.

Comment: just edited the question!

Comment: Does it mean you want to disallow leading zeros? Try `let regex = "[1-9]\\d*(?:[.,]\\d)?"`

Comment: Literal `100,3` is never recognized as a `Double` (code will not compile) so the comma check is useless.

Comment: no, I would just like to let the numbers be of the format X or X,Y or X.Y 
(X stands for many digits, Y has to be only one digit). This is a validate function from a input text field, and some keyboards use , instead of . in their numerical pad

Comment: Then just use `let regex = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d)?"` to match 1+ digits and optionally a dot or comma + 1 digit after.

Comment: You need to validate the actual string from the text field.  Converting it to a double and then trying to validate it afterwards will never work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression is the wrong approach since it doesn't really deal well with locale specific issues.

A better approach would be to convert the string into a number using `NumberFormatter`. Then convert the number back into a string using another `NumberFormatter` setup with your specific requirements (such as at most one decimal digit). Then see if the original and the newly formatter strings match or not.

If they match, the user entered a valid number in their given locale meeting your desired requirements.

Answer (score 2):

try this regex:

`^\d+([.,](?!\d{3,})\d+)?$`

in english: start of string, followed by one or more numbers, followed optionally by a decimal and more numbers, *if* 3 or more digits do not follow the decimal (the negative lookahead part)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kUBt6I/2)